# Docker Ruby SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong signature type

Tags: ruby, docker, httparty, faraday

I have ruby 2.7 in a Docker container running a rather simple HTTP client using Faraday:

```rb
conn = Faraday.new("https://jinio.com.ph")
conn.post("/tracker", {p: @code}.to_json, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})
```

This code returns a SSL Error "wrong signature type" inside the container.

```
Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong signature type)
```

Any ideas on how this can be resolved? FYI, if I run this on Mac OS, the code runs without errors

My Dockerfile if this helps:

```
FROM ruby:2.7
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client nano
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app

# Script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start server
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: When you run bash with your container, does the same request with `curl` or `wget` works?

Comment: Running curl inside the container failed as well:
`curl: (35) error:1414D172:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong signature type`

Comment: Would be nice to know more about why your container is getting an ssl error on your domain. Maybe your certificate provider root certificate is not shipped with your container?

Comment: Alternatively, even not recommended, you can skip the SSL check: https://gist.github.com/doubleotoo/3942158

Comment: I was having same issues after upgrading my Ruby container from 2.5 to 2.6. I found this article describing what I think is the issue: https://medium.com/@andrewhowdencom/mysterious-ssl-tls-network-connection-failures-in-debian-buster-52c29a661cb3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem, solved with change in Dockerfile.

after `FROM ruby:2.7` add

`RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Origin source (in Japanese):

https://qiita.com/masayuki14/items/c34eafb9d6130e2c5b67

Comment: Are there any security concerns with changing the SECLEVEL?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution didn't work out of the box because I needed to fix that issue on `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` using `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`.
The solution I found at https://askubuntu.com/a/1233456/306766 worked for me.

> You need to add this to the beginning of your config file
> (`/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`):
>
> ```
> openssl_conf = default_conf
> ```
>
> And then this to the end:
>
> ```
> [ default_conf ]
>
> ssl_conf = ssl_sect
>
> [ssl_sect]
>
> system_default = system_default_sect
>
> [system_default_sect] MinProtocol = TLSv1.2 CipherString =
> DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this with a very old Rails application running in a Docker container (using base image of `ruby-2.3.3`).

This [very helpful blog post](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-a-lets-encrypt-related-expired-root-certificate-on-an-old-server) held the solution, but in summary the old ca-certificate for Let's Encrypt expired in 2021. There's a valid version shipped in ca-certificates (see steps in the post to confirm) but the expired one needs to be commented out.

Adding this line to my Dockerfile solved this issue for me:

```
RUN sed -i '/^mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3/s/^/!/' /etc/ca-certificates.conf \
  && update-ca-certificates -f
```